# jquery autocomplete enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Currently the autocomplete action when pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on a selected element is to put that elements value into the input box.

How can I modify the behavior so that pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on an element triggers that elements embedded url. To simplify I'd like to make the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key have the same behavior as a mouse click on a returned element.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Easy !

```
$(".quicksearch-input").autocomplete({

  minLength: 4, // minimum length to trigger suggestions

  // ... + other configuration options

  select: function(e, ui) { // define select handler

    var uri = ui.item.link; // where ui.item.link itself is defined in your object which you composing when retrieving JSON from endpoint

    window.location = uri; // forwarding to the URL obtained

  }, // select //
});
```

But everything depends on your way of implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This is the function that is called when you select an item and hit enter.  The hacky code you see in this function extracts the href from the link and redirects to that url.

```
$("#searchBox").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        var p = data.toString();
        p = p.replace('<a href="', '');
        var url = p.substr(0, p.indexOf('"'));
        p = p.replace('</a>', '');
        p = p.substr(p.indexOf('>') + 1, p.length - p.indexOf('>') - 1);
        window.location = "" + url;
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try keypress event

have a look on the events

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/